# Use AzureFunction to connect to LogicApp

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a LogicApp which can connect to an Azure database and SFTP etc, so all API connections have been created which can be viewed in API Connections in Azure.  But for simplicity for now I just want to be able to connect to the API shown below simply by calling this JSON Body:

```
{
    "SFTPConnection":"WhiteStuffSFTP"
}
```

[image]

The code to my very basic LogicApp is below, which simply connects to the WhiteStuffSFTP API shown above.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Get_file_content": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['WhiteStuffSFTP']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('L2hvbWUvVGVzdC5jc3Y='))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "L2hvbWUvVGVzdC5jc3Y=": "/home/Test.csv"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "SFTPConnection": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "WhiteStuffSFTP": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/fc4e844a-4aad-4e33-8f54-41494548f8b5/resourceGroups/ws-dataplatform/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/WhiteStuffSFTP",
                    "connectionName": "WhiteStuffSFTP",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/fc4e844a-4aad-4e33-8f54-41494548f8b5/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/uksouth/managedApis/sftpwithssh"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which works perfectly fine when the API connection has been hardcoded in the LogicApp:
[image]

So I tried going into the code within LogicApp and changed

```
"connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['WhiteStuffSFTP']['connectionId']"
                        }
```

to

```
"connection": {
                            "name": "@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['SFTPConnection']))}"
                        }
```

But I'm getting this error:
[image]

Comment: I don't believe you can.  The API connections are used in LogicApps and not accessible outside of that.  You just need to use the standard approach for connecting to SFTP or SQL if using a funciton.

Comment: Hey @tommyhmt! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in Logic app. You can follow the [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/22b83226-e7a4-4168-bd31-3547367f4959/choose-api-connection-dynamically-in-logic-app?forum=azurelogicapps) to achieve this.
Or you can use the [Durable Function](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/azure-durable-functions-patterns-best-practices) to achieve your needs.

Refer [here](https://laurentiu.codes/2020/09/08/dynamically-select-orchestrators-in-azure-durable-functions/)

Comment: Hi, sorry I've been away and only just managed to try this out now.  Was following the method from [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/22b83226-e7a4-4168-bd31-3547367f4959/choose-api-connection-dynamically-in-logic-app?forum=azurelogicapps) so I've edited the original question slightly to show more screenshots etc.